# Error JRLoader.loadObject de JasperReport

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, ireport

Soy nuevo en esto de `jasper report`, no se si me falta algo o por que me sale este error:

Mi linea de Código con error:

```
JasperReport reporte = (JasperReport) 
JRLoader.loadObject("ReporteComisiones.jasper");
```

Es un proyecto maven, con respecto al jasperreport solo tengo esta dependencia

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

el error en la linea de código es

> no suitable method found for loadObject(String)

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Que error te esta dando?

Comment: no suitable method found for loadObject(String)

Comment: Las librerías te faltan, para que pueda cargar cómo se debe el reporte. Fíjate en lo que sería las librerías.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te esta dando es que estas enviando un `String` cuando se espera toda la ruta completa del reporte.

Entonces lo que puedes hacer es mandar el nombre del reporte a una función que encuentre la ruta completa donde tienes  tu reporte, como este ejemplo:

```
  private InputStream reportFile(String file) {
        return ((ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext())
.getResourceAsStream("/resources/reports/" + file);
    }
```

Aquí ya llamas al reporte como lo tienes en tu código

```
JasperReport MasterReport = (JasperReport) 
JRLoader.loadObject(reportFile("ReporteComisiones.jasper"));
```

> Nota: "/resources/reports/" esta ruta puede variar según donde tengas tu carpeta de reportes